# Is Donald Trump's campaign a false flag?

Tags: politics, donald-trump

Jeb Bush recently suggested that Donald Trump's campaign is a false flag for Hillary Clinton, and I have heard a few people mention this sort of thing in the past as well.  What evidence is there to support this, and what evidence is there against this?

I'm not really familiar with the situation, but this whole idea strikes me as fishy.  I'm trying to determine whether this is plausible, or just an interesting, but wrong, conspiracy theory.

Comment: How would we ever know the secret motivation of a person?

Comment: I should clarify and ask if there is actually any solid evidence that points to this?  Does it seem plausible?

Comment: The edit has been made. Hopefully that helps a bit.

Comment: One of our earliest rules was [political motivations are off-topic](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/621/politics-beliefs-and-motivations-questions-should-not-be-allowed-here). We want to give definitive answers, and there is no way of answering this question definitively. Trump has denied it; that's not sufficient. Even if he had admitted it, that would likewise be insufficient. This is not a hypothesis that can be scrutinised with a skeptical bent because it is unfalsifiable.

Comment: You could maybe ask if Trump's campaign is as a point of fact *benefiting* Clinton's, but that's also not easy to answer because there are so many variables and unknowns

Comment: The conservative newspaper Daily Telegraph endorsed Jeremy Corbyn for leadership of the Labour Party arguing it would render the Labour Party unelectable.  Also: enjoyable (but fictional) film touching on a related idea: [The Ides of March](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1124035/).

Comment: Figured I'd add this here. New Wikileaks documents show that Hillary wanted Trump to get nominated. https://twitter.com/i/web/status/785615427913199616

Comment: The election result pretty-much disproves this idea.